# Properties in IronPython: eternal loop

Tags: c#, python, properties, ironpython

Well, I am very noob in python and now I try to translate c# code into IronPython.
Have problem with properties:

Here is my class for example (got it from http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property):

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self.temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value")
        self.temperature = value
```

When I try to get this property from another class like this

```
cb = SomeClass()
temp = cb.to_fahrenheit()
```

I got an eternal invocation with printing "Getting value" and finally StackOverflowException. What's wrong with properties? This is a little piece of task for translating getters and setters with ref parameters, but I cannot go ahead with this error.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your getter and setter should be returning/setting self.**_**temperature (the backing field), not self.temperature (the property) - by self-referencing, you caused an endless loop.